# Open URL on didEnterRegion in background

Tags: ios, location, background-process

I am trying something for an Enterprise App and I wish to launch a URL when the phone enters a region even when the application is in the background. However, the below code doesn't work. The callback is triggered but opening of the URL fails.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{

NSLog(@"Entered a Region");
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);

}
```

I know there are many restriction with background so I am wondering is this even possible? Is there any work around other than using a UILocalNotification?

Comment: One thing to check (and I assume you're not really going to be browsing to stackoverflow) is that the url you're browsing to is actually reachable by the device. For example if you're trying to browse to a web-site that's internal to your enterprise, can you browse to that same URL using Safari on the device?

Comment: I am just using stack overflow as a place holder. The main issue here is that safari is not being launched. So I am wondering if it is possible to run an application from a background callback.

Comment: Thinking it through, I'm suspicious that it would work. Imagine that your app has gone to the background, and the user's doing something else (say with Safari even) then magically they see Safari come up and go your page. I can't imagine that UX being the sort of thing Apple would promote. Happy to be proved wrong, but it just doesn't sound likely.